# Python - Assign a variable in lambda apply function to calculate correlation

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, apply, correlation

I have a dataframe that has the potential to grow in column size exponentially. I'm trying to calculate the correlation between two columns, multiple times. Part of the correlation calculation is with the growing number of columns. I'm creating the columns needed for the correlation calculation in a FOR loop and when i try and calculate the correlation, I get an error saying:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'
```

I've tried assigning the new column name to a variable and putting that variable in the lambda function, but that also doesn't work.

How to I update the correlation piece of the code to use the new columns in the FOR loop?

Here is the for loop that creates the new columns. colname is a list of all column names:

```
for col in colname:
    df[col+'_RR'] = df['p_'+col] - df['r2500_ret']

    df[col+'_sec_rr'] = df['ret'] - df[col+'_RR']
  
    # Calculate Correlation
    dfcorr = df.groupby('symbol').apply(lambda v: v.col+'_sec_rr'.corr(v.col+'_RR')).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'jets_correlation'})
```

Comment: The problem is that `v.col+'_sec_rr'` is parsed as `(v.col) + '_sec_rr'`.  I believe you'll need to use `v[]` notation, not the `v.` notation.

Comment: Anytime you have a lambda that complicated, you should just make it a separate function.  The separate function can even be a local function inside your current function.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Roberts answered the question in the first comment. It was a simple change in notation for . to []. Thanks Tim!